# Как сделать красивое отображение доменов glassfish ?

Tags: glassfish

Ищу как можно сделать нормальное отображение доменов, то есть вместо

```
http://domain.com:8080/myproject/chtougodno
```

стало

```
http://domain.com/chtougodno
```

---

Можно ли это сделать средствами glassfihs, если нет то какими ?

Answer (score 1):

Использую вот такую схему

```
http://localhost.ru/page/название_страницы_в_паке_page
```

Сделал через web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

И пакет для обработки запросов:

```
package page;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author vekaravaev
 */
@WebServlet(name = "page", urlPatterns = {"/page"})
public class page extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> and
     * <code>POST</code> methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        /*
         * Начальные действия для генерации страницы
         */
        String text = request.getRequestURI();
        text = text.replaceAll(request.getContextPath(), "");
        text = text.substring(1, text.length());
        String[] url = text.split("/");
        /*
         * отображение страниц
         */
        try {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet page TEST</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet page at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("<div>url " + request.getRequestURI() + "</div>");
            //HttpServletRequest req = new HttpServletRequest();
            //req.setAttribute(name, value);
            try {
                getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/page/" + url[1] + ".jsp").include(request, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("e: ");
            }

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```